# Double of Total Problem

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Table1

```
ID  |  WorkTime
-----------------
001 |  10:50:00
001 |  00:00:00
002 |  ....
```

WorkTime Datatype is **varchar*(.

```
SELECT ID, 
       CONVERT(varchar(10), TotalSeconds1 / 3600) + ':' + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(varchar(2), (TotalSeconds1 - TotalSeconds1 / 3600 * 3600) / 60), 2) + ':' + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(varchar(2), TotalSeconds1 - (TotalSeconds1 / 3600 * 3600 + (TotalSeconds1 - TotalSeconds1 / 3600 * 3600) / 60 * 60)), 2) AS TotalWork 
From  ( SELECT ID, 
               SUM(DATEDIFF(second, CONVERT(datetime, '1/1/1900'), 
               CONVERT(datetime, '1/1/1900 ' + WorkTime))) AS TotalSeconds1 
          FROM table1 
      group by ID) AS tab1 
where id = '001'
```

The above Query is showing "double the total of time"

For Example

From table1 i want to calculate the total WorkTime, when i run the above query it is showing

ID WorkTime

```
001 21:40:00
002...,
```

But it should show like this

```
ID Worktime

001 10:50:00
...,
```

How to avoid the double total of worktime. How to modify my query.

Need Query Help

Comment: @Gopal, what happened to the previous (duplicate) question that you asked yesterday?  I spent some time on it and not is deleted?

Comment: @Philip - The error is coming in different way, I finally found out the error. It is giving double the total which means 22:00:00 instead of 11:00:00. There is error in the query.

Comment: Is the worktime the actual time of day or the duration of work done?

Comment: No duration of work done. Just i want to add the total of Work Time column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After creating tables and adding data as described in the question, I still got the expected answer of `10:50:00`.  Not sure why it is not working for the OP...

To simplify the query and to enhance performance it might be better to change the type definition for `WorkTime` from *varchar* to *int*.   Then save the work interval as total seconds.

It would then be simple to sum the interval amounts and then perform a display format on the final value.  (Preferably in the application and not in the database)

Comment: Just tested on our system and the query behaves as expected. OP should post a (none)working example, complete with creating the table and inserting records.